# cannot fix error "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."

Tags: python, django, debugging, configuration, settings

Hi I just started my Django project today and during my attempt to `python manage.py migrate` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 216, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 36, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/home/danni/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.autodetector import MigrationAutodetector
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.questioner import MigrationQuestioner
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/questioner.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .loader import MigrationLoader
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 9, in <module>
    class MigrationRecorder:
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 22, in MigrationRecorder
    class Migration(models.Model):
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 100, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 244, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/danni/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 127, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Then I ran `python manage.py check` and got following error:

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

---

So far my project structure is:
I created a settings folder at `project/project/settings` and have three file `base.py`(The one I renamed and moved from project/project/name), `production.py`, `staging.py`, `test.py` which only includes one line `from base import *` and also an empty `__init__.py`.

For the account app it's under `apps/account`. And I already added `urls.py`. Also, I have added 'account' under `INSTALLED_APPS` in `base.py`.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: check comma between Installed apps, post your settings.py

Comment: It sounds like Django can access your settings files, but cannot access the `SECRET_KEY` value. Have you changed it to refer to `os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have changed the `settings.py` file to settings folder, you have to update the `manage.py` file to point out to the new settings module, In `manage.py`

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'example.settings')
# Here update the string 'example.settings' to the new settings module
# e.g os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings.test')
```